# cannot resolve method setGroup

Tags: java, android, methods, notifications

I wanted to assign a notification to a group with `setGroup()` for stacking notifications and summarising them.

Like [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html)

```
final static String GROUP_KEY_SAPPHIRE = "group_key_emails";
NotificationCompat.Builder oneBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        oneBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.warning_icon)
        .setContentTitle("Warning: ")
        .setContentText(message)
        .setPriority(0x00000002)
        .setLights(Color.GREEN, 500, 500)
        .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_SAPPHIRE)

        .addAction (R.drawable.ic_action_accept_dark,
            getString(R.string.ok), warningPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager oneNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    oneNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, oneBuilder.build());
    editText.setText("");
```

But I always got the response that the method setGroup couldn't be resolved.
I've imported the **.v4.support library**.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be too late but for everyone else had the problem like me, you should update the .v4.support library. to at least support-v4:21 in the Gradle build.gradle app dependencies, this style of stacking is available from API 21+ .